# How to exclude invalid Excel input from being transferred to SQL?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm considering if I can bypass input values that lack a corresponding record in the database. This way, I can execute queries with valid numbers without encountering errors, while marking the invalid ones in red color after full run within the Excel sheet.

Current error for non valid data: Object Variable or with block variable not set.

My Example code -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim vault As String ' Corrected data type
    Dim prtlst As ListObject
    Dim connPD As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsPD As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim PDConnString As String
    Dim SelStringPD As String
    Dim cLocalPath As String
    Dim rowCnt As Long ' Changed data type to Long
    Dim PLoc As Range
    Dim infoArray As Variant
    
    ' Change placeholders with actual connection information
    PDConnString = "Provider=YourProvider;Data Source=YourDataSource;" & _
                  "User ID=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword;"
    
    Set prtlst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Set connPD = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rsPD = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    connPD.Open PDConnString
    connPD.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set PLoc = prtlst.Range(2, 1)
    
    ' Initialize rowCnt
    rowCnt = 0
    
    Do While Not IsEmpty(PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 0).Value)
        SelStringPD = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ValueText = '" & PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 0).Value & "';"
        Set rsPD = connPD.Execute(SelStringPD)
        
        If Not rsPD.EOF Then
            ' Ensure fully qualified range reference
            PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 1).Value = rsPD.Fields("FileName").Value
            PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 2).Value = rsPD.Fields("Path").Value
            PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 3).Value = rsPD.Fields("LatestRevisionNo").Value
            ' Fully qualify the range reference
            PLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("VAULTPATH").Value & rsPD.Fields("Path").Value & rsPD.Fields("FileName").Value
        End If
        
        rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
    Loop
    
CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    ' Close and cleanup resources
    If Not rsPD Is Nothing Then
        If rsPD.State = adStateOpen Then rsPD.Close
        Set rsPD = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Not connPD Is Nothing Then
        If connPD.State = adStateOpen Then connPD.Close
        Set connPD = Nothing
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on, that's the more important part.

Comment: `Set rsPDM` and then `If Not rs.EOF Then` also `Set Loc = prtlst.Range(2, 1)` and then `prtLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 0).Value` ?. It would be helpful to see the complete code including the variable declarations.

Comment: Shouldn't `Range(2, 1)` be `Cells(2,1)` to reference cell A2.  `Range(2,1)` would throw the "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Also need an `Exit Sub` just before the `ErrorHandler:` line - the error handler shouldn't be part of the main body of code.  As it is your code will always hit the `MsgBox "Error:  ".....` line eventually.  Actually... it would get stuck in a loop there.  After the error message it will resume at CleanExit and hit the messsagebox and `Resume CleanExit` line again.

Comment: `"SELECT******* = '" & prtLoc.Offset(rowCnt, 0).Value & "';"` doesn't look like it would run.   `SELECT *` would select everything from a table, but I expect `SELECT **********` would return an error.

Comment: I've included an updated example. Please note that the 'SELECT ***' statements are placeholders for illustration purposes and do not reflect actual queries. Additionally, I'm encountering difficulty in handling invalid inputs from the range and I am looking for a general idea of how to skip them if it is not a valid input.

Comment: Give an example of a valid and an invalid input.

Comment: For Example: If there is data in my SQL database consisting of items like "Apple" with corresponding prices, when I input a particular item into a cell, the system will validate it and return the corresponding price in the spreadsheet. If I input "Orange" and it is not found in the database, the system will proceed to the next row until it reaches the last user input, retrieving the data from SQL accordingly.

Comment: Ok so the code skips records it can't find, on which line does the error `Object Variable or with block variable not set.` occur ?

Comment: Finally it worked! Using the GoTo statement with a labeled point in the loop, such as NextIteration, allows for conditional skipping of code within the loop based on specific criteria, efficiently controlling the flow of execution and avoiding unnecessary processing in VBA. In the provided code, when no matching record is found, execution jumps to NextIteration, bypassing further processing for that iteration and proceeding to the next row.